# comparing a column to a String in a database?

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I need help with comparing a column to a string. There is a column in the android database and it stores on and off in strings. I need to compare the column to "On" string and if there is any On in that column i need it to return true and if there is no on in the database return false how do i do this ?

my code

> public boolean QuickTime(){
>
> ```
>       String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE_TABLE_QUICK WHERE ALARM_ID_QUICK LIKE 'On' ";
>       Cursor mCursor = databaseConnect.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
>       if(mCursor.getCount()>0)  //if at least one record contains 'on'
>           return true;
>       else
>           return false; //no record was found with the word 'on'
>   }
> ```

Comment: you need to compare the column name or the record in the column?

Comment: I need to compare all records in the column and if one or more of them equal "On" it should return true other wise return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy (not the best) way to do it is with [Rawquery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) .
so all you would have to do is something like:

```
private boolean containsOn(SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase){
    String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE status LIKE 'on' ";
    Cursor mCursor = mSQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
    mCursor.
    if(mCursor.getCount()>0)  //if at least one record contains 'on'
        return true;
    else
        return false; //no record was found with the word 'on'
}
```

all you would have to do is pass your sqlLite database, change the table name and the status column for your column name.

Comment: Thanks i added some code to my post that i was trying to use but could not get working

Comment: well you are comparing the "cursor" if its >0 but its not the cursor, its the count as its in my "if" code.
just change it for:
return databaseConnect.query(DATABASE_TABLE_QUICK, ALARM_MODE + "=" +ison, null).getCount() > 0;

Comment: but its strange that its allowing you to run that query since android documentation about query requires at least 7 parameters.

Comment: its not allowing me .. i just looked again and i had delete in instead of quary

Comment: When i try your code and put in my table . it says no such table?

Comment: i added more code above .. it just says no such table even that there is?

Comment: could you paste the code of your database? and the part where you define your databaseConnect.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite> create table on_c(id int,onoff varchar(3));
sqlite> insert into on_c (id,onoff)values(1,'ON');
sqlite> insert into on_c (id,onoff)values(2,'OFF');
sqlite> select * from on_c;
1|ON
2|OF
select case count(*) when 0 then 'true' else 'false' end from on_c where onoff like '%N';
false
```